What are some books to gain prerequisites for answering questions about multidimensional geometry?
I am engineering person and I am reading convex analysis and optimization and also error control codes. My issue is that there are few concepts which the authors of these books assume but I am not able to answer, for instance:
a) Equation of a line passing through two points in an n-dimensional space.
b) Given two basis vectors [1,-1,0] and [0,1,-1] show that the lattice they generate is an hexagonal lattice in $\mathbb{R}^3$. [from Lattice Coding for signals and networks by Ram Zamir]
what should I read in mathematics to be able to answer these prerequisites. Though I know a little bit of linear algebra, concepts like span and space and subspace. But still I have difficulty answering these questions.
Can one suggest some readings or books to understand these.

Since you have some Linear Algebra under your belt, I’d recommend “Linear Algebra and Multidimensional Geometry” by Efimov. Here’s the free text: https://archive.org/details/linearalgebraandmultidimensionalgeometry/

Just note there are no exercises.

The second statement is quite wrong. For the first, if you’re talking about parametric equations (vector form), it’s the same in $n$ dimensions as in $2$ or $3$.

@Ted Shifrin  I have corrected the statement.
